# Make static variable to sum values in class for output, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variables, static

New to Objective-C and had this assignment in which I was to output values of students in two different courses using class/methods.

That was the easy part, the part I need help on is how to declare a static variable and use this variable to add together the values of all the students and output the value.

I've seen all kinds of examples and threads and I'm really trying to wing it on this but I can't figure out how to apply the concept with this problem. It's easy to do in another language but not the same with ObjC...

**The code is as follows:**

```
//
//  main.m
//  yadda yadda
//
//  Created by yadda yadda on 8/26/14.
//  Display the number of students in two different courses.
//
//  Copyright (c) 2014 yadda.self. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


//---- @interface section ----

@interface Students: NSObject

-(void) setCourseOne: (int) a;
-(void) setCourseTwo: (int) b;
-(int) courseone;
-(int) coursetwo;

@end

//---- @implementation section ----

@implementation Students
{
    int courseone;
    int coursetwo;
}

-(void) setCourseOne:(int) a
{
    courseone = a;
}

-(void) setCourseTwo:(int) b
{
    coursetwo = b;
}

-(int) courseone
{
    return courseone;
}

-(int) coursetwo
{
    return coursetwo;
}

@end

//---- Program section ----


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

       Students *myStudents = [[Students alloc] init];

       [myStudents setCourseOne: 8];
       [myStudents setCourseTwo: 24];

        NSLog(@"There are %i students in this class", [myStudents courseone]);
        NSLog(@"There are %i students in this class", [myStudents coursetwo]);

        //Third output statement for sum of all students
        NSLog(@"There are %i students in all of the classes", [myStudents courseone]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a simple addition?

```
NSLog(@"There are %i students in all of the classes", [myStudents courseone]+[myStudents coursetwo]);
```

If you want to use a *local* variable, you can use:

```
int total = [myStudents courseone] + [myStudents coursetwo];
NSLog(@"There are %i students in all of the classes", total);
```

There are other comments that could be made to improve your code, but as you are following an assignment we'll assume you'll be coming to those things as your progress.

HTH

Comment: Great this answers part of the question, but where do I declare the variable at? In the interface section or outside of it to make it global? -Also please do include comments if you wish, the more info the better honestly

Comment: The `int total` is the declaration, the `= ...` is its initialisation. It sounds like you need to read up on kinds of variables, declarations , etc.

Comment: That's not what I mean, but nevermind I'll figure it out haha. Thank you for the help.